# I need tips to have a key-value array as class property in c# winform

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, dictionary, user-controls

I am trying to design a DataGridView as userControl in a C# Windows application.
And I need to manipulate text of a column at run time.
Now I need to set some properties as a key-value at design time.
first parameter is column index and second is a text style I made it before as enumeration. 
In other words I need to set something like this at design time. 
(ushort,myenum.somthing)

```
private Dictionary<ushort,dateFunctions.shamsiDateStyle> _ShamsiDateCols = new Dictionary<ushort,dateFunctions.shamsiDateStyle>();

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("sets the indexes of shamsi date columns.")]
    [Category("UniLib Tools")]
    [DisplayName("Shamsi Date Columns")]
    public Dictionary<ushort,dateFunctions.shamsiDateStyle> ShamsiDateCols
    {

        get { return _ShamsiDateCols; }
        set { _ShamsiDateCols = value; }
    }
```

[image]

What is the best approach to achieve that.
Any advice will be appreciate.

Comment: Where do you instantiate and populate your dictionary?

Comment: I didn't do that . should I do?

Comment: If your dictionary does not exist yet (i.e. `shamsiColumns = new ...`), how do you expect to get passed the `if (_ShamsiDateCols != null)`?. And if you do not populate the dictionary, how do you expect `foreach (var item in _ShamsiDateCols)` to do anything?

Comment: I think at the first line of code above I create the dictionary object.

Comment: where should I instantiate and populate that?

Comment: I see. In C#, there is a difference between declaring a variable, and instantiating it. You could for instance say: `int five;`. This wouldn't mean that the variable 'five' holds anything yet, only that you are now able to see it within your code. If you want to use it, you need to instantiate it: `five = 5;`, note the '='. Now for your dictionary, you only declared it. If you want to use it, you'll need to instantiate it BEFORE you want to use it. So either do it in the constructor of the class you're using the dictionary, or do it before you do the `if (_ShamsiDateCols != null)`.

Comment: NOTE: In C# an `int` actually does not require instantiation as it is a struct. I just used it because it's a simple type to explain with.

Comment: that was my wrong. I just missed copy that part of code. I did instantiate it in this class. exactly above the definition of property.

Comment: So update your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `ArrayEditor` for `Dictionary` type because `Dictionary` by its nature is not `IEnumarable` so the editor can never iterate to to show items.

It doesn't seem using `Dictionary` is a good approach for you, `Dictionary` is mostly used to handle performance issues(access to a dictionary item has a constant complexity).

Maybe it does not help you but I suggest you to use `ArrayEditor` otherwise you have to design your own custom editor. First add `System.Design` to your references then use the following :

```
     [Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.ArrayEditor),
 typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)),
                  DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]

            public dateFunctions.shamsiDateStyle[] ShamsiDateCols
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
```